# Temporarily block access to all POST and login functionality

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am looking for a rule to temporarily block from users accessing my site without disabling the site completely - so only read access, on my varninsh server I have the following so far:

```
 /**
 * Temporally restrict access.
 *
 */

if(req.http.host ~ "domain.tld") {

if(req.http.user-agent != "SYS-ADMIN") {

    if(req.method == "POST" || req.url ~ "^/wp-login.php$" || req.url ~ "^/wp-admin") {

        return(synth(503));
    }
}
```

}

would this suffice or am missing something?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better do to it on the application site rather than in Varnish?

Comment: The User-Agent bit looks rather dogdy - I would recommend looking into ACLs, e.g. https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-example-acls.html

Comment: Also the regexes to match "/wp-login.php" might be a bit too specific - just add a query parameter and it does not match anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `req.method == "POST"` did the trick and disabled access to the site from users not being able to write to the DB without blocking the whole site.